# Where can I see the options accepted by the field API for the widget type?

Tags: 7, entities

Where can I see the options accepted by the field API for the widget type?

```
$instance = array(
  'field_name' => $field_name,
  'label' => 'Demofield Demo',
  'description' => 'This is a demonstration text field.'
  'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'text_textfield',
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default options for each widget are listed in the hook_field_widget_info() implementation.

You can find all such implementations in core by searching for "_field_widget_info": You can find a list of all core implementations of that hook by searching for "_field_widget_info": http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/_field_widget_info

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a preset list of widget types; the widget types are the ones defined from modules that implement fields. Using the following code, you can get the list of all the widget types implemented by the enabled modules:

```
$array = module_invoke_all('field_info');

foreach ($array as $id => $info) {
  print $info['default_widget'];
}
```

The code essentially invokes all the implementations of [hook_field_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7), and print what is defined as default widget.
If you have installed Devel, instead of `print` you can use `dsm()`.

If you want to know the settings available for the field implementation, then you need to look for the implementation of [hook_field_settings_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field_ui--field_ui.api.php/function/hook_field_settings_form/7), such as [list_field_settings_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--modules--list--list.module/function/list_field_settings_form/7), or [text_field_settings_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--modules--text--text.module/function/text_field_settings_form/7).

```
function text_field_settings_form($field, $instance, $has_data) {
  $settings = $field['settings'];

  $form = array();

  if ($field['type'] == 'text') {
    $form['max_length'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield', 
      '#title' => t('Maximum length'), 
      '#default_value' => $settings['max_length'], 
      '#required' => TRUE, 
      '#description' => t('The maximum length of the field in characters.'), 
      '#element_validate' => array('_element_validate_integer_positive'),
      // @todo: If $has_data, add a validate handler that only allows
      // max_length to increase. 
      '#disabled' => $has_data,
    );
  }

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: You can also look at the source code of the widget select in the field UI, which contains all possible values.

Comment: thx for response. But as much as I see the options for each one?
e.g. the number of lines in textareas?